# Periodically change SSL certificate at runtime

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, certificate

I am building an internal PKI for our microservices. The way it works right now is

There's an Offline Root CA and online Issuing CA

on start up a microservice

- generates a keypair , a csr and keystore
- loads the CA certificate into it's truststore
- sends a request to Issuing CA to sign the certificate
- gets new certificate and stores it

What we envision is to create a short lived (say 24 hours or less in validity) certificate for each microservice and when it is about to or when it expires the microservice should generate a new CSR and get it signed and continue working as usual. Is this possible and what are the challenges to be faced if were to go in this direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside why you need such a low refresh time for an internal network, your architecture is viable

To consider:

- The issuing CA must be online and should process the CSR and return a valid certificate during the startup of the microservice and have a reasonably short response time
- The public certificate of the Offline Root CA should be included previously in the trustsore of each microservice. I would recommend to include it programmaticaly to avoid security risks
- Check if your SSL server is hot-swappable and the certificate can be updated during start-up or they must be done before the microservice starts (not all servers support it)
- Note that you will not be able to use SSL-pinning

---

SSL pinning is implemented adding the server certificate to the truststore instead of the issuing CA to avoid that other certificate of the same CA is accepted

The certificate is usually installed manually an offline in the client truststore but in your case you have to distribute each certificate to the clients that are going to use the microservice. The solution is unpractical due to you have to.securize the channel, distribute them to each client, install them and ensure all steps are synchronized.

Do not forget also that the old certificates must be deleted from truststore because if they are present, they still would be accepted by clients

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I would like to know why I wouldn't be able to use SSL pinning if I am able to do CA pinning of the issuing  CA certificate ?

Comment: See the updated answer with the reasons why ssl pinning is not usable.

Comment: A correction on my part I meant CA pinning with Root CA certificate. Yes I now see what you mean about the certificate distribution being a problem, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Are there any certificate pinning and key distribution solutions you could suggest aside from offline certificate installation ?

Comment: the ones I know are offline or embedded in the application. I mean mobile applications or desktop with one server and an SSL certificate that does not change frequently. I have seen systems similar to yours, but relying on the CA root, not the final certificate.